# Is ASP.NET 3.5 training track independent from ASP.NET 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-2.0

I am a newbie to the ASP.NET world and I want to take the straight way for fast learning and to start producing some applications.

I want to take ASP.NET certification and training but I found that there are a lot of new features in ASP.NET 3.5 and many new features and concepts also was introduced in ASP.NET 2.

I want to take the track for ASP.NET 3.5 but can't know if it depend on the previous track for ASP.NET 2 or not?

What is the track name?

Remember I know nothing in ASP.NET, but want to start with the true track from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net 3.5 is basically v2.0 with some extensions. If you look inside %WINDIR%/Microsoft.Net/Framework/ you'll see v2.0 and v3.5 but note that v3.5 lacks things like a CONFIG folder. This is because the v2.0 CLR is used by v3.5.

IMO you should study 2.0 to get all the fundamentals right first and then look at the extensions like LINQ, ASP.Net AJAX etc. once you have a good understanding of the basics.